# Script Element Between Head and Body. [HTML5]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

When validating with W3C, I received the response:

> script element between head and body. [HTML5]

How is this specific to HTML5 versus regular XHTML validation?

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<link href="services.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

  <div id="header">
  </div>

  <div id="body">
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
  </div>

</div>
<script></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's pretty straight forward.

Comment: You have a script element between your closing head tag and your opening body tag.

Comment: Don't know about the original close reason, but in your edited markup there is no longer a script element between head and body.

Comment: You haven't edited your question since I commented on it. Your current markup does not reproduce the problem you are describing, so I simply can't reopen this. (I could, but then I'd have to close it with a different reason, which is pointless.) Please do not flag your question for our attention until you have responded.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You placed your scripts on an invalid spot.

You should place them within head or body tags. Every time you can, put them at the end of the body. This is to avoid blocking html rendering while dowloading scripts, improving site responsiveness.

From [`w3.org`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1)

> The SCRIPT element places a script within a document. This element may appear any number of times in the HEAD or BODY of an HTML document.

Comment: Their verbiage here makes it seem like they're addressing the number of times it can be placed, but not so much WHERE it can be placed.

Comment: @downvoter: would you mind sharing what's wrong with the answer?

Answer (score 3):

Just like the message says, this is invalid (not just script tags, but any tags):

```
</head>
<tag/>
<body>
```

Those `<script>` tags need to be descendants of *either* `<body>` or `<head>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your scripts within the `body` tag, at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

As the message suggested, you have some scripts "floating" out `head` or `body` tags.

Move this inside head or body tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.4">    </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.4" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.fancybox').fancybox();
    });
</script>
```