# how to add dynamically code before body tag using wordpress hook or filter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I am working on developing a WordPress plugin. I want to add some content before body tag and after head tag.

As a example:

```
</head> 
    some code add here dynamically  using hook or plugin or any other way to add code here (html content dynamically ) 
<body>
```

Comment: I don't really think you can hook between `<head>` and `<body>`. Look here for all the relevant hooks: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/

Comment: @flomei is correct - see here for more. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348140/script-element-between-head-and-body-html5

Answer (score 1):

You can use this --

```
add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'your_function' ), 1 );

function your_function(){
    echo "your tag here";
}
```

Comment: this in head section i want to add after head section before body

Comment: try using javascript insertAfter function.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML standards do not allow something to be between </head> and <body>, I think.

Besides that, what do you think should be placed there? And how would you call that area when viewing the whole document?