# How does Postman get data from a response, which is not JSON or XML?

Tags: html, postman

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
        <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <LINK href="style.css" type=text/css rel=stylesheet>
        <META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="position.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="common.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="copyright.js"></script>
        <!--[if lt IE 7.]
    <script defer type="text/javascript" src="pngfix.js"></script>
    <LINK href="style2.css" type=text/css rel=stylesheet>
    [endif]-->

    </head>
    <script>
        var session_key='09fcf555eb2814024ee22e47cacfb04e';
    //get user power
    var NOWPATH = get_now_url();
    var user_power="0";
    if ( NOWPATH == "/" )
            NOWPATH = document.location.pathname.substring(1,document.location.pathname.length);

    /* get page url*/
    function goto_home()
    {
        if(user_power == '0') //Admin
            goto_page("quicksetup.asp",0);
        else //User
            goto_page("wan_sub_u.asp",0);
    }
    </script>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

As is above, it is a HTML response, I would like to get the variable "session_key" value from the HTML text. But I don't know how to do it with Postman.

Comment: Use [Test Scripts](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test_scripts/)

Comment: adding `<script>` in between `<head>` and `<body>` tag is quite innovative ...never seen that before.

Comment: [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16348140/8566549) ;)

Comment: @Vusal :  Yes, I know the test scripts, but how? Could you give me a script to finish it. I tried 'xml2Json' and 'cheerio', but it failed.

Comment: What failed? You might need to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this in tests:

```
var sessionKey = responseBody.match('var session_key=\'([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\'')[1];
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("session_key", sessionKey);
```

And then look in environment variables for a value and reuse where it needed.